# Workflow and Process builder field update

Tags: workflow, process-builder, administration

Can anybody please clarify the Difference between the Workflow field update and Process builder field update? (field update through process builder vs field update through workflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For updating related records, Process Builder can update any field on
>   any related record, where Workflow can only update some fields on a
>   parent record of a Master-Detail relationship. Process Builder can
>   also update multiple related records in a situation when all of a
>   record’s child records need the same update.

**Scenario 1** – Whenever there is any change into Contact Name update Latest Contact custom field of Associated Account with the latest Changes into the account name.

For this scenario,  We will go for process builder because using  workflow we cannot update related record other than master detail

**Scenario 2** – Update all related case and Contacts with the same phone of account whenever account phone changed.

Process Builder will be the right tool to use here as we need to update all contacts and cases there may be more than 1 and Process Builder allows you to do the same.

- If field update is done using Process builder, then the record will go through complete Save cycle again.
- If field update is done using Workflow field update, then Custom
  validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules will not run
  again. [Read here more.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

> Also, Process Builder finally gives admins the ability to set the
>   exact order of operations, whereas with Workflow we had no control. No
>   more complex workarounds to be able to ensure things happen in a
>   certain order!